# Theme Resolver Example of Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, themes

How can I get list of themes by programming in Theme Resolver Example of Spring MVC?

Answer (score 0):

Following configuration you need to do in the xml file.

```
<!--  Configuration for Theme Selection -->
    <!-- Note: property files for theme-XXX should be exist into build path.should be in:/WEB-INF/classes/ -->
        <bean id="themeSource"
        class="org.springframework.ui.context.support.ResourceBundleThemeSource">
            <property name="basenamePrefix"  value="theme-"/>
        </bean>

        <bean id="themeChangeInterceptor"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.ThemeChangeInterceptor">
            <property name="paramName" value="theme" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="themeResolver"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.SessionThemeResolver">
            <property name="defaultThemeName" value="green" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="handlerMapping"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
            <property name="interceptors">
                <list>
                    <ref bean="themeChangeInterceptor" />
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
```

And then in your property file you need to specify the path to your CSS file for respective theme.

```
css.style=/Web/resources/css/style.css
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You should google it first and try it your self and then ask any question if you get any exception.

For this we will add following code into spring-servlet.xml file.

```
<bean id="themeSource"    class="org.springframework.ui.context.support.ResourceBundleThemeSource">         
<property name="basenamePrefix" value="theme-" /> 
</bean>  

<!-- Theme Change Interceptor and Resolver definition -->
<bean id="themeChangeInterceptor"    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.ThemeChangeInterceptor">     
<property name="paramName" value="theme" /> 
</bean> 

<bean id="themeResolver"    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.CookieThemeResolver">     
<property name="defaultThemeName" value="default" /> 
</bean>   

<bean id="handlerMapping"    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">     
<property name="interceptors">         
<list>             
<ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />             
<ref bean="themeChangeInterceptor" />         
</list>     
</property> 
</bean>
```

In the above configuration, first we have added themeSource bean. Notice that this bean is an instance of class ResourceBundleThemeSource and we also have specified a property basenamePrefix with value “theme-”. ResourceBundleThemeSource class will load the property files containing theme definition starting with prefix “theme-”. Thus, if we have defined 3 new themes in our project (default, black and blue) then we will create 3 property files while will have certain configuration properties. Also these files will be placed under the project classpath.

Next, we defined an interceptor bean themeChangeInterceptor which is an instance of class org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.ThemeChangeInterceptor. Also note here that we have specified a property paramName with value theme. This interceptor is invoked whenever a request is made with parameter “theme” with different values.

Once the themeChangeInterceptor intercepts the change in the theme, the changes are then stored in the cookies using class org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.CookieThemeResolver. We have configured this class in our spring-servlet.xml configuration file. Also note that we have specified default theme name with this bean.

We are almost done with the changes and last bit that is remaining is to add a functionality for user to select the theme from UI. For this we will change the header.jsp file and add 3 links with different themes. User can click on any of this link and change the theme of webapplication.

This whole information can be found at this link http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-3-mvc-themes-tutorial-example/

Hope this will help you.